# Redis-backed session state not saving everything

Tags: redis

We are trying to move from server session (IIS) to Redis-backed session.  I updated my web.config with the custom sessionState configuration.  I'm finding that only SOME of my key/value pairs are being saved.  Of the 5 I expect to be in there, there are only 2.  I verified all my code is ultimately hitting HttpContext.Current.Session.Add.  I verified that my POCOs are marked as serializable.  Looking at monitoring, I see that it adds the first two pairs, then everything after that just doesn't make it.  No hit, no rejection, no exceptions.  Nothing.

Anyone ever see this?  Know where I could start to look to resolve?

TIA,
Matt

---

Update 1: I've switched to using a JSON serializer to store my data.  Same thing.  Doesn't seem to be a serialization issue.

---

Update 2: I've now downloaded the source code, compiled and am debugging it.  The method SetAndReleaseItemExclusive, which seems to send the session items to Redis, is only hit once, though it should be hit more than once as my web site handle SSO and bounces from page to page to load the user and such.  Have to investigate why it's only firing once...

Comment: The big thing that isn't being saved is my "authenticatedUser" object which holds their ID and what not that I need around the app.  Fortunately, the mechanism that saves this to session is interfaced so I'm able to use an implementation to talks to Redis directly, not through session.  That works perfectly.  It's almost like the session state isn't flushing out to Redis?

Comment: What code? You're going to need to include more for context here. "My Redis isn't working" isn't a sufficiently detailed technical explanation. Remember Redis has the `MONITOR` statement so you can see what commands, if any, are being run and you can use that to investigate if Redis is actually being used.

Comment: Thanks @tadman.  I'm not going to paste my entire code library.  I figured saying that I verified the code was hitting HttpContext.Current.Session.Add would suffice in saying that "yes, verified the data is being added to session."  I also stated "looking at monitoring, I see..." and then go on to state what I see.  As I said, there is nothing after the first 2 key pairs (of the 5 I expect).  If you have more pointed questions...

Comment: It'd help if you take the time to break up that big ball of words into smaller, more digestible paragraphs. "Monitoring" can mean anything (Windows Event Viewer, etc.), so try and be specific, and whenever possible, speak in terms of code or actual output, not a vague description of same.

Comment: @tadman are you aware of any issues with this set up with AJAX calls?  Per my Update 2, I'm finding that SetAndReleaseItemExclusive is not being hit upon the wrap up of an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Turns out that my AJAX request to an "API" endpoint without my MVC app did not have the appropriate session state attached.  Therefore, the SetAndReleaseItemExclusive was never called.  Adding this fixed it:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath == "/api/user/load")
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        else
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
    }
```